# Git merge two branches without a common ancestor

Tags: git, merge

We had two branches in Bitbucket, `master` and `feature`. We moved these two branches to GitLab recently. There are some commits to `master` which were not included in `feature` before the move.

Now we have these branches in GitLab. Both the branches have advanced by few commits. If we do a simple `git merge` from `master` into `feature`, it doesn't merge those extra commits from `master` (the once that were committed to `master` but not to `feature` on Bitbucket). All the other commits to `master` after the move to GitLab get merged into `feature` without any issue.

When we compare the branches, we see they differ by the code included in these commits. But the simple merge doesn't bring that code to `feature`.

Is there a way to merge the two branches without a common ancestor?

Comment: maybe cherry pick those commits? just a guess. don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks@user1984! Those changes were committed when we were hosting our repo on Bitbucket. Now we are on GitLab. Cherry picking won't work here.

Comment: You're definitely misunderstanding something about Git here, because if these truly had no common ancestor, you would get an error message that effect. But it's not clear what you *did* do. Git isn't really about *branches;* Git is about *commits*. When you move a repository, you're really just copying *commits*. Each copy of a repository has *its own* branch names, but they literally *share* the commits. The commits themselves are numbered (by hash ID) and two different copies of a repository have the same commit if they have ones with the same number (hash ID).

Comment: If the Bitbucket and GitLab copies of the *repositories* are in sync, they will have the same *commits*. Their branch names could be completely different; as long as they have the same *commits* you can do the same work with them. (It's *humans* who insist on having branch names match up, because if they don't, we all go nuts trying to keep this stuff straight, as we don't work with commit hash IDs. Well, *I* don't, I can't speak for everyone. :-) )

Comment: It's the *commits*, not the branch names, that *are* the history. All relationships are embedded in the commits. No commit can ever be changed, by anyone or anything, ever, so once made, they're frozen for all time, and if the two repositories have the *same* commits, they have the same history.

Comment: Meanwhile, the `git merge` command simply doesn't *mean* "make branches the same". That would be quite bad, since we'd like to *add* work someone else did without *erasing* our own work. So there's something off when you say, in effect: "the branch tip commits differ, but merging doesn't make them the same": it's not SUPPOSED to make them "the same"!  (I know that isn't quite what you said, and not what you meant, but it's hard to know what you meant without actual computer output.) And, If Git says "already up to date", that means the *history* is already included.

Comment: So: clarify your question by including things like `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` output, and/or the shell session output where you run `git switch branch1; git merge branch2` and so on.